# Как сделать анимацию скрытия и раскрытия custom view

Tags: java, android, android-animation, transition

### Задача:

Я хочу сделать анимацию скрытия и раскрытия view по нажатию кнопки.

---

### Проблемы:

Сначала я пытался это сделать меняя visibility (GONE, VISIBLE), но это вызывало некоторые баги при анимации. (Я использую Transition API)

Затем, я решил сделать это со Scale: прошлые баги пропали, но появились новые (там были проблемы с отрисовкой (мой view состоит из нескольких других дочерних view-элементов)).

---

### Мой CustomView элемент, который я хочу анимировать:

```
class SearchAdditionalView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val transitionSet: TransitionSet by lazy {
        val transitionSet = TransitionSet()

        with(transitionSet) {
            addTransition(ChangeBounds())
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
            duration = 200
        }

        transitionSet
    }

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.include_search_navbar_addition, this)

    }

    fun toggle() {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent as ViewGroup, transitionSet)
    }
}
```

---

### Вопрос:

Есть ли какие-нибудь практики в создании таких анимаций и как их применить?

Comment: Гугл недавно [анонсировал MotionLayout](https://medium.com/google-developers/defining-motion-paths-in-motionlayout-6095b874d37). Инструмент позволяет реализовать любые мыслимые анимации дочерних View внутри такого контейнера. Может вам подойдет такой вариант.